# Web - Arial font is displayed differently on several devices

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts, font-family

On my website, for some reason the Arial font is displayed differently on several devices.

It was fine and the complaints started to arrive approximately a month ago and I suspect that the root cause is somewhere locally (browser or OS).
All the problematic users sit on different versions of Windows and mostly use Chrome (but no everyone).

Tried to investigate this issue but did not find something in common.

Is anybody faced such a problem already?

Code:

```
<h1 style="font-family: Arial;">Title</h1>
```

Comment: put your font in directory of your website and set path of your font.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put your fonts file in your website directory and set path from your directory.
(some times maybe that device has not your font.)

in top of your css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "BYekan";
    src: url("../font/BYekan.eot?#") format("eot"), url("../font/BYekan.woff") format("woff"), url("../font/BYekan.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

use it:

```
body{
    font-family: "BYekan";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a reason for this.  There's nothing to state that any given device, or browser for that matter, must adhere to any given standard for the rendering of fonts.  Consequently, it's prudent to create overall website designs with the assumption that text will render inconsistently across browsers/devices.  As soon as you assume rendered text will "fit in to this/that space" you're in trouble.

Instead create a design that deals with the issue of font rendering elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be surprising, and what you call the "root problem" is actually not a problem, but simply how fonts work in the browser.

Without an explicit `@font-face` rule and real font sources, you're telling the browser that you don't really care what it loads, as long as the font that gets loaded matches, roughly, what you're asking for. If you ask for "Arial" then the browser will ask the OS for a font that claims to be in the Arial family, and different devices may (or rather, *will*) have different versions of Arial installed. So your content's going to look different for different devices.

However, and something a lot of people forget, it doesn't matter if that's the case. What matters is that your site content looks consistent. People are not going to look at your site on two computers at the same time and then notice that they don't look pixel-identical. Individual users are going to look at your content on one device at a time. So: is the look *consistent on a single device*? Great, you're done. Which version of Arial is actually being used is pretty much irrelevant in that case.